# Array_Search always returning false from file_get_contents php

Tags: php

I have a textfile, consisting of the following, and a couple of other things, but i've ommitted them here

```
###Sprint-Name###
SPRINT 20180403
###DEV-Number###
DEV-1039
###Functionality###
To do a thing
```

that document was uploaded via a form

and my code is as follows:

```
<?php
//Import the errorhandler
include_once('errorHandler.php');

//First of all, we need to get the contents of the test document so that we can process it
//The test document needs to be exploded based on newline
$testDocument = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents($_FILES['testDocument']['tmp_name']));

echo '<pre>';
    var_dump(array_search("###Sprint-Name###", $testDocument));
    print_r($_POST);
    print_r($_FILES);
    print_r($testDocument);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

but the var dump is returning `bool(false)`, even though my `$testDocument` array is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ###Sprint-Name###
    [1] => QA Reporting
    [2] => ###Dev-Number###
    [3] => DEV-1231
    [4] => ###Functionality###
    [5] => To do a thing
)
```

if the array $testDocument is forced to be:

```
$testDocument = array("thing","###Sprint-Name###","other");
```

then that returns `1`, which is correct as the needle is at 1 in the haystack

Maybe it's to do with the encoding on the `###`, how can I check this, and how can I force it to a specific encoding? Thanks.

Edit: I tried removing the `###` from my strings and using different characters, just in case PHP thought they were comments or something, but this has no effect.

Comment: You want to start by using `var_dump($testDocument)` for the debug output, not print_r. Do that, and report back here what that shows.

Comment: I did some testing, and it looks to be a problem with exploding by `PHP_EOL`. I made it work with `explode("\r", $input);`

Comment: I guess this is the reason: `Note that PHP_EOL represents the endline character for the current system. For instance, it will not find a Windows endline when executed on a unix-like system.`

Comment: Correct. (var_dump just helps catch stuff like this better, because it shows you the length of the elements as well.) Btw., instead of explode & file_get_contents, you might just use file.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is splitting/exploding by `PHP_EOL`.
If the files were created on a different system than the executing one, `PHP_EOL` might not catch the right, or all new-line, carriage-return characters. This results in a value with a left over trailing `\r` in your case.
See here:

```
var_dump($testDocument[0]);
//output: 
// string(18) "###Sprint-Name### "
// trailing character at the end
```

So, to solve that you could do a `preg_slit`, with which you can split by several characters:

```
<?php

$input = <<<EOT
###Sprint-Name###
SPRINT 20180403
###DEV-Number###
DEV-1039
###Functionality###
To do a thing
EOT;

$testDocument = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/", $input);

var_dump($testDocument);

$key = array_search("###Sprint-Name###", $testDocument);
var_dump($key); // int(0)
```

Or use `file` instead of `file_get_contents`, as @CBroe recommended.